# Uniqueness of the diagonal form of metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

For Schwarzschild solution, if we use the coordinates ($t$,$r$,$\theta$,$\phi$). the metric in these coordinates are diagonal, my question is, is there exist another set of coordinates ($t^{'}$,$r^{'}$,$\theta^{'}$,$\phi^{'}$) which one or several of them are linear independent of the coordinates ($t$,$r$,$\theta$,$\phi$)? Or all coordinates that keep  metric diagonal are of the form ($ut$,$wr$,$n\theta$,$m\phi$) where $u,w,n,m$ here are all constants.

Comment: They don't need to be constant rescalings;  any redefinition $\{ t'(t), r'(r), \theta'(\theta), \phi'(\phi) \}$, where the "primed" coordinates are arbitrary monotonic functions of the unprimed coordinates, will also lead to a diagonal metric.

Answer (score 8):

The diagonal form of the metric is highly non-unique and we can illustrate that with a much simpler example than Schwarzschild. The $\mathbb{R}^3$ metric is diagonal in Cartesian coordinates:

$$ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2.\tag{1}$$

Now work in spherical coordinates. This transformation is far from a mere rescaling:

$$x=r\cos\phi\sin\theta,\quad y=r\sin\phi\sin\theta,\quad z=r\cos\theta.\tag{2}$$

The metric reads:

$$ds^2=dr^2+r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2).\tag{3}$$

Observe that the metric is also diagonal. Another example is cylindrical coordinates:

$$x=\rho\cos\phi,\quad y=\rho\sin\phi,\quad z=z,\tag{4}$$

in which the metric reads $$ds^2=d\rho^2+\rho^2d\phi^2+dz^2,\tag{5}$$

and we again get a diagonal metric. Therefore indeed there are in general many different charts, not related by just rescaling the coordinates, in which the metric is diagonal.